# Как сделать резиновый header?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать шапку сайта резиновой, чтобы подстраивалась под разные размеры браузера.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="header">

 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header{
    background: url(../img/header.jpg);
}
```

Comment: `width: 100vw;`?

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос. Что значит «чтобы подстраивалась»? Если речь о размере блока, устанавливаете в CSS ширину и высоту в процентном соотношении от размера родительского элемента. Если о фоновом изображении, то используйте `background-size`, `background-repeat`. Если хотите разные стили для разных размеров экрана, используйте медиа-запросы.

Answer (score 1):

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url("http://www.avionindia.com/images/Header.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Comment: В ширину я бы использовал `%`

Comment: background-size: cover; - розтягивает пропорционально контейнеру изображение фона, 
background-position: center; - центрирует фон,
background-repeat: no-repeat; запрещает повторять изображение

Comment: И что? Зачем вы мне это рассказали? Я говорю про ширину меню. В хроме `vw` берёт и полосу прокрутки за ширину и может появиться горизонтальный скролл

Comment: тогда делайте overflow: hidden; чтоб обрезало все лишнее и делало контент по размеру девайса

Comment: Если так, то нужно использовать `overflow-x: hidden`  и это не всегда удобно

Comment: если у меню есть выпадающее подменю, то тогда overflow: hidden; все портит, но если нет, тогда можно использовать

Answer (score 0):

Так должно работать:

```
.header{
    background: url(../img/header.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Этот способ не работает. Картинка есть, но никаких изменений не происходит при изменении экрана

Answer (score 0):

```
.header {
    background: url(../img/header.jpg) no-repeat center;
    backgriund-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

`height: 100vh` - задает высоте равную высоте окна

Comment: А зачем шапке высота, равная высоте окна? о:

Comment: Иначе вопрос не имеет смысла. Если не нужно - не используй.

Comment: Этот способ не работает. Картинка есть, но никаких изменений не происходит при изменении экрана

Comment: Работает, только если поставить тег img, вставить туда картинку и присвоить класс header

Comment: А какие изменения Вы хотели увидеть? Вы не уточнили в вопросе.

Comment: Резиновый header. Не о чем не говорит?

Comment: Ни о чем. Что должно происходить при изменении размера окна? В чем заключается его "резиновость" ?)